# ubuntu web server not responding remote requests except ssh

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, iptables, remote-server

It is a remote server, I can ssh to login.

Originally I successfully set up `nginx+php-fpm+mysql+tomcat`, and all went well. I could brows `http://118.244.237.197` and `http://118.244.237.197:8080` (tomcat).

Then for security, after searching for simple yet affective solutions, I installed fail2ban (and maybe something else), but even after that, I remember things are working.

Today, after rebooting the server, I can `ssh`, and `curl -XGET http://localhost` on server responded with homepage; But the server is not responding to remote `http://118.244.237.197` browser request.

I am new to linux servers, guess this is something related to firewalls. Here is the output for `iptables -L` if related:

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    fail2ban-ssh-ddos  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
    fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

    Chain fail2ban-ssh-ddos (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Where should I check to see the root cause, and what should I do to fix?

Comment: It was the firewall outside. After posting at askubuntu, superuser and here... Consulted the provider. Hosting company didn't allow direct requesting through IP. Request with domain is working fine.